# linux: Access a directory containing a space

Tags: bash, shell, whitespace

In a script, I have this line

```
#!/bin/sh

log="${var}logs/console logs/since2_%m-%d-%Y.log" # <-- console logs has a space
```

how can I access this file?

putting quotes like:

```
log="${var}logs/"console logs"/since2_%m-%d-%Y.log"
```

cancels out the quotes around it, and escaping the quotes makes it try to find a file containing the character "

Comment: I think you need to provide more information, perhaps a trivial test program.  Some of the error messages you show could not happen with the code.

Comment: @Seth those are provided below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not what is quoted in the question.  Here is an example script which works.  Note the quotes around the USAGE of $log in addition to the definition.  If you want further help, post the complete script or a minimal working subset which people can run to reproduce the problem.

```
#!/bin/sh
var=/tmp/
log="${var}logs/console logs/since2_%m-%d-%Y.log"
mkdir -p "$log"
rmdir "$log"
fortune | tee "$log"
echo ----
cat "$log"
```

Comment: +1 This is a good example: it (1) quotes the value when assigning it to 'log' and (2) quotes used when expanding "$log" as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble you're having is probably where you use $log, you should probably be using "$log" to preserve the spaces.

Comment: didn't work `./starter.sh: line 5: log=/home/duke/aa/servers/demo/var/logs/console logs/since2_%m-%d-%Y.log: No such file or directory`

Comment: agreed, the definition of log is going to be ok, but when you use $log in another statement it will be interpreted as separate words without surrounding quotes.

Comment: @Kevin: karmakaze's answer is correct. If you still have a problem, it's in a different part of the script. Post the whole script.

Comment: The whole scrip is just this: `tail -n0 -f -s 0.01 $ladderlog | $parser | (while true; do $tron --userconfigdir $userconfigdir --vardir $var; done) | tee -a $log`

Comment: @Gilles @karmakaze could you please provide a sample of how i would do this?

Comment: You still need quotes when setting log="..." in addition to when using the value "$log" as an argument.

Comment: @Kevin: **Always use double quotes around variable substitutions** (unless you intend for the value of the variable to be split into words and each word treated as a glob pattern). `tail -n0 -f -s 0.01 "$ladderlog" | "$parser" | (while true; do "$tron" --userconfigdir "$userconfigdir" --vardir "$var"; done) | tee -a "$log"`

Answer (score 1):

the variable $IFS holds the field separator, which by default is space, so try with

```
oldifs="$IFS"
IFS="
"

log="${var}logs/console logs/since2_%m-%d-%Y.log"

# do whatever you want with $log now

IFS=$oldifs
```

Comment: does not work, I get this: `tee: logs/since2_%m-%d-%Y.log no such file or directory`

Comment: If this solves your problem, please consider accepting it as the answer also - thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to have today's date in that filename:

```
log="$(date "+${var}logs/console logs/since2_%m-%d-%Y.log")"
touch "$log"
```

I'd recommend you use `%Y-%m-%d` as that sorts both cronologically and lexically.

Answer (score -2):

I think `log="${var}logs/console\ logs/since2_%m-%d-%Y.log"` should work. Try once
The idea is to escape the [SPACE]

Comment: does not work, I get this: `tee: logs/since2_%m-%d-%Y.log no such file or directory`

Comment: No, that would reach a directory called `console\ logs`, with …-e-backslash-space-l-…